# WP shortcode outputs shortcode as text

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I'm trying to use shortcode in post to display gallery but on website it puts out shortcode itself as text.
I'm using

```
<?php the_content();?>
```

in php file.
Same shortcode works well with

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[shortcode here]')?>
```

but in this case I need it to be shortcode in post editor.

Comment: You just need [shortcode here] in the post editor. No need of do_shortcode function

Comment: That's exactly what I did and only the shortcode itself shows up on website.

Comment: I got it work only with do_shortcode but I need it to work in ordinary way too

Comment: It should work. are you sure you are using the same shortcode tag in wp editor also check in both visual and text editor if there is any typo

Comment: They are same and no typos

Answer (score 0):

No need to write PHP code and just put `[shortcode here]` in the WordPress Post Editor.

Comment: That's what I did and it outputs [shortcode here] as text in website. [supsystic-gallery id=1] in real life.

Comment: Wordpress Editor has two tabs, visual and text. Try to write inside text editor.

Comment: As your comment, I saw [supsystic-gallery id=1]. Please try to use [supsystic-gallery id="1"].
https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use short code in wordpress post editor then no need to write php code.

And if you want to user the_content() in any wordpress .php file then you need to write and follow code pattern.

for example (example of single.php)-

```
<?php
  while (have_posts()) : the_post();
  the_title(); 
  the_content();
  endwhile;
?>
```

Lets consider that you are on the checkout page, in the `dashboard > Pages > Checkout Page` you enter this `[woocommerce_checkout]` and
In page-checkout.php file of your wordpress you can write your custom code to make it work.

Here is an example of my custom code :

```
<?php
  if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) :
    the_post(); ?>
      <div class="container">
          <div class="checkout-page my-4">
              <?php the_content(); ?>
          </div>
      </div>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Sorry for bad English :-P

Comment: When I write shortcode in Post Editor it shows the short code itself as text on website. And I have the loop also on php.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding following code in your active themes functions.php

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'do_shortcode' );
```